# How do I win the Omnium?

Tags: mario-sonic-london-2012

For the life of me, I cannot understand how this event really works, let alone how to win it.

I know that I have to pick a rank, and then press A like mad to sprint, but I don't understand what the two have to do with each other, much less what sort of strategy is needed. I know that if I choose a higher rank, then I spend more stamina, but other than that, I can't really figure out how to do well or win.

Any tips on how to beat Omnium?